# How to zoom in Highcharts Android

Tags: android, highcharts

I am developing an android application for HTC desire S. I am using highcharts to plot a graph. I am not able to zoom the curve though. I used zoomType : 'x', but it doesnt work. Can anyone tell me what might be the problem. Also, if there is some other way to zoom.
Below is my code:

```
 $(function callJS() {  

var carter = dataLoader.getfhr();
var myArray = carter.split(" ");
 for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)

    { myArray[i] = parseFloat(myArray[i]); }   

var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
           renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'spline',
           zoomType: 'x',
            spacingRight: 20,
             backgroundColor : '#E8E8E8'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fetal Heart Rate'
        },
        subtitle: {
           // text: 'October 6th and 7th 2009 at two locations in Vik i Sogn, Norway'
        },
        xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        lineColor: '#CC3333',
         tickColor: '#CC3333',               
        //minorTickInterval: 1,
       // minorTickLength: 0
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'FHR values'
            },
            min: 1500,
            max: 3500,
            minorTickInterval: 10,
            lineColor: '#CC3333',
            lineWidth: 1,
             //tickWidth: 1,
             tickColor: '#CC3333',
            //minorGridLineWidth: 'auto',
            //gridLineColor : '#CC3333',           
            //minorTickInterval: 10,    
            //minorTickLength : 'auto',     
           // gridLineWidth: 2,
            alternateGridColor: null,
            plotBands: [{ // mark the weekend
            color: 'pink',
            //from: 120,
           // to:160
        }]
        }, 
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                     return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + this.x + ': ' + this.y;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                lineWidth: 4,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 5
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true,
                            symbol: 'circle',
                            radius: 5,
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    }
                },

            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'FHR value',
            data: myArray,  
            color: '#383838',
            //dataLabels: {
             //   align: 'left',
              //  enabled: true
          //  } 
        }]

    });
});

});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that the zoom functionality works just fine on Android 4.2.1, Android 2.x doesn't support a lot of features that HighCharts offers because it uses a different renderer, as Android 2.x doesn't support SVG's.

> ### Android 2.x
>
> Android 2.x doesn't have SVG support built in, so we have
>   created a separate renderer based on the canvg library for this
>   system. This solution has some limitations:
>
> 1. Using Highstock on Android 2.x is not recommended as it relies
>      heavily on zooming and mouse interaction
> 2. Shared tooltip is always enabled.
> 3. During first render, the canvg renderer + rgbcolor.js + canvg.js
>      (concatenated to one file) will be downloaded from code.highcharts.com
>      This is configurable with the global.canvasToolsURL option.
> 4. Chart and series animation is turned off.
> 5. Show/hide series from the legend is not enabled. Series and point touch events are not enabled.
> 6. **Zooming is not enabled**.
> 7. Using the Renderer API directly to add shapes to the charts is not supported.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but unfortunately I need to work on HTC Desire S only. I switched to achertengine.

Answer (score 1):

Please take look at http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/compatibility, probably HTC has old Android, because in the 4.0 version zoom works fine.